# Efficient way to handle large runtime-generated tile maps?

Tags: objective-c, c, performance, memory-management

I am coding a 2 dimensional, tile based (orthogonal tiles) iPhone game. All levels are procedurally generated when the app is first played, and then persist until the user wants a new map. Maps are rather large, being 1000 tiles in both width and height, and the terrain is destructible. At the moment it is rather similar to [Terraria](http://www.terraria.org/), but that will change.

To hold map/tile information I am currently using several 2 dimensional c style arrays. This works well, but I am concerned as to the amount of memory this takes up, as the arrays are all defined as `short array[1000][1000]`, which takes up (1000 * 1000 * sizeof(short)) bytes of space.

This is not particularly desirable when the iPhone doesn't have an incredibly large amount of memory to work with, especially when the user is multitasking. The main problem is that there is no way that I can use a specific tile map format such as .tmx, because all the levels are procedurally generated. Performance could also be an issue, because if a tile is destroyed at index(x, y), then I need to change the data in that index. I have also thought about writing tile map data to a text file, but I think there would be difficulties or performance issues when accessing or changing data.

Keeping all this in mind, what would be an efficient and fast way to handle my tile data?

Comment: If it's procedurally-generated, why can't you just generate tile values when they're needed, rather than generating the whole thing up-front?

Comment: That's a good point: it's mainly due to the process. My map uses a [drunkard walk](http://pcg.wikidot.com/pcg-algorithm:drunkard-walk) method of placing some of the tiles; I don't know how I would do this except all at once, just due to the nature of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feeling on this is Core Data structured such that each tile element has relationships to the tiles around it. There's some non-trivial overhead here, but the advantage is that you can release tiles that aren't onscreen from memory and fault them back when you need them. As you move in a direction, you can query for the tiles in that direction, and you can fairly cheaply dump memory when you're in the background. This would get rid of the "several" 2D arrays and move all the data into a single object. In principle, the grid could be infinite in size this way, since everything is by relationship rather than coordinate.

You could similarly approach the problem using SQLite, querying for rows and columns in a given range. You might mark the objects as `NSDiscardableContent` and put them in an `NSCache`, which could dramatically improve memory performance. You could still generate an effectively-infinite grid as long as you allow coordinates to be both positive and negative.

Comment: This sounds promising! Which of the two do you think would be better, taking into consideration that I haven't been programming for years and years? (which would be easier to implement and extend, if needed?)

Comment: I would probably lean towards Core Data since they've already done much of the hard work and optimization for you, particularly if you're not already highly familiar with SQLite.

Comment: I just looked into Core Data, and it seems promising. Thanks for pointing me towards that! I'm marking this as my answer.